# Why is `tail` still borrowed after the `while let Some() = xxx` loop?

Tags: rust

I've been solving some leetcode problems where I hit an issue I could not explain.

[Here is the full source code:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=29f3f2080b87b93c8190cd81ddddbb4b)

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}

impl ListNode {
    fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode { next: None, val }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = Some(Box::new(ListNode {
        val: 1,
        next: Some(Box::new(ListNode {
            val: 2,
            next: Some(Box::new(ListNode { val: 3, next: None })),
        })),
    }));

    let mut tail = &mut list.as_mut().unwrap().next;

    // This compiles fine
    // while tail.is_some() {
    //     tail = &mut tail.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    // }

    // This compiles fine
    // while let Some(ref mut node) = tail {
    //     tail = &mut node.next;
    // }

    // However this does not
    while let Some(node) = tail.as_mut() {
        tail = &mut node.next;
    }

    *tail = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(4)));
    println!("{:#?}", list);
}
```

And this is the error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `*tail` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:39:5
   |
35 |     while let Some(node) = tail.as_mut() {
   |                            ---- borrow of `*tail` occurs here
...
39 |     *tail = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(4)));
   |     ^^^^^
   |     |
   |     assignment to borrowed `*tail` occurs here
   |     borrow later used here
```

Why is `tail` still borrowed **after** the `while let Some() = xxx` loop ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the interaction of `while let ...` and the [scrutinee](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/glossary.html#scrutinee) `tail.as_mut()` in that `while let`, which is a value expression in a place expression context.

Simply put, in order for the body of the `while let` loop to be able to access the binding (`node`), the compiler needs to borrow `tail` (created before the loop), call `as_mut()` on the `Option`, keep the implicit [temporary](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/expressions.html#temporaries) borrow on that `Option` alive(!), and bind the value `as_mut()` returns to `node`; as far as the compiler knows, the lifetime of `node` depends on that `Option`, because it is funneled through `&'a mut tail -> as_mut(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut ListNode`.

When you then reassign `tail = &mut node.next`, this is still a value of the implicit lifetime `'a`, borrowed on the original temporary which the loop created.

When you then assign to `*tail` after the loop, a conflict occurs: There is an implicit borrow on the original `Option`, which is used to call `as_mut()` to first create `node` and then `tail`, but now you are assigning to - as far as the compiler can see - **that Option**. But you can't invalidate that `Option` while it is borrowed, so an error occurs.

This is why the compiler points to `borrow of *tail occurs here` (notice the dereference) in the scrutinee-position of the `while let`-loop and then - confusingly - points to `*tail = Some(...)` being the point where the borrow is used.

The other two examples compile fine because there is no temporary created in the scrutinee to do the method call on `Option`.